# Angular 2+ template parse errors in karma/jasmine tests

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I'm having some issues running Angular tests on some components, but the components work fine in production. I keep getting this error message:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'app-date-picker' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-date-picker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-date-picker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      </nav>
    </div>
    [ERROR ->]<app-date-picker></app-date-picker>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
```

I only have one module here:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DatePickerComponent } from './date-picker/date-picker.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DatePickerComponent,
    ...
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

My component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss']
})

export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private dateService: DateService) {
        this.startDateRange = new FormControl(this.dateService.startDateRange);
        this.endDateRange = new FormControl(this.dateService.endDateRange);
    }

    ngOnInit() {...}
    updateDateService() {...}

}
```

I can get *some* of these errors to go away by adding `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` to the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` object, but they are replaced with a `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` error message, which doesn't help me in the slightest. 
Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Please let me know if I need to provide any more information, thanks!

edit:

Here's the spec file for one of the components that fails:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DatePickerComponent } from '../date-picker/date-picker.component';

import { MyComponent } from './my-github.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
        DatePickerComponent
      ],
      // schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please add your spec file?

Comment: Added spec file. Thanks!

Comment: Whether `MyComponent` and `DatePickerComponent` are declared in the different module?

Comment: @amit There is only one module, it's posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I Know its late but it will helpful for the others

You are getting `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` error comes while you are running `ng test` this is because `TestBed` will emulate a module in which it try to load your `DataPickerComponent` , in angular if you use custom HTML tag you will get `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` exception it is already handle while you are running angular application (angular2+) so you don't get this exception while normal running of application but it will comes when you run the test cases using `ng test` so to avoid this you have to add this in `schemas` option.

```
 `   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ 
                DataPickerComponent
              ],
        providers: [GridWidthService],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
       }).compileComponents();  `
```

After adding this line you will get another `Dependency Injection error` because in your component you have injected a Service `DataService` .so you also have to do that same in your `test spec file` .

> Key Point is that you have to add same data in .spec.ts file for component like  adding services in the provider section , if you are using any module then add it in the import section because in each test case **TestBed** emulate the module so you have to provide each dependency for that component in the **configureTestingModule({/* Compnent specifications*/})** function

Hope it will works

Answer (score 0):

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DatePickerComponent } from '../date-picker/date-picker.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './my-github.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
        DatePickerComponent
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I did this and added the contents of the spec file in the original post. Looks like i'm still getting that error.

Comment: Sorry I missed that thing, please check it now it should work

Comment: Hi @Sáähil, Do you mean import it into the spec file? or in the module? 
Also, why is ng-bootstrap important to making specs work properly?

Comment: You need to import in your spec file. You need to include it in spec because you are using it in ts file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried installing ng-bootstrap and importing it but it didn't work. Are you saying I'm using it because of the `new FormControl()` statement? If so, i'm importing `{ FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms"`

Comment: can you import it from angular/core, as you did in ts file. Also include it in imports as I mentioned

Comment: import NgbModule from @angular/core? I'm still confused as to why I need NgbModule in the first place. What tells you that I'm using a ng-bootstrap element?

Comment: NgModule and include NgModule.forRoot() in imports

Comment: You said import NgModule from @angular/core - I'm getting an error message `NgModule.forRoot() is not a function` when I run tests. You had previously said to import `NgbModule` but when I import it from `@angular/core` i get a message that says `@angular/core has no exported member 'NgbModule'`. 
I very much appreciate the help, but I'm still confused - What tells you that I need to install @ng-bootstrap?

Comment: please check it now and let me know

Comment: Hi Sáähil, I have made no changes since you last responded. What would you like me to check? I am still getting error messages.

Comment: I edited the response please let me know what errors you get after copy n paste of my response